# How do I stop charging the battery way prior to 100% in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, power-management, battery, netbook, acer

I'm thinking about using a netbook as an OpenBSD server.  I'd like it to have UPS -- so the integrated battery is quite useful.

However, I'm very familiar with the batteries going dead very quickly if stored at 100% charge, plus topped up back to 100% all the time is guaranteed to make it only worse.  I'd like to avoid this, to ensure the battery could easily cover one to two hours of power loss for years to come -- which means that charging should only start when below 40% to 50%, and stop at about 60% to 80% (else, it'll probably already only hold at most 60% of charge after a year, and be entirely useless some short time after that).

There's a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/preventing-battery-from-charging), which has also been [cross-posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21286/how-to-prevent-battery-from-charging-while-on-ups), and it appears to suggest that ThinkPads and Dell laptops have some proprietary features to this effect; but what about cheapo Acer netbooks?

Comment: Realizing you're on openBSD, but something like this available there? http://askubuntu.com/questions/218148/stop-start-battery-charging-through-software

Comment: @slm, thanks for the link, but it doesn't look like [the question you mention](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218148/stop-start-battery-charging-through-software) reveals of how to stop the battery in an Acer netbook from charging in Ubuntu, either.

Comment: I wasn't sure, I only have thinkpads, so no: `/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh`?

Comment: My understanding is that your `/smapi/` comes from [`tp_smapi`](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi) specifically, which is ThinkPad-specific.

Comment: OK, will keep looking.