# How to disable AC power supply from CLI

Tags: scripting, power-management, battery

[This article](http://www.batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/do_and_dont_battery_table) among others suggested the following to prolong
 battery life:

> Keep cool. Operate in mid SoC of 20–80%. Prevent ultra-fast charging and high loads (most Li-ion)

The main issue here is trying to keep the battery from becoming unusable prematurely. `acpi` can give the power information on battery percentage to trigger a script, but I don't want to be constantly plugging and unplugging my laptop.  I generally keep my laptop plugged in, but I am looking for a program/script to disable the AC power supply without physically disconnecting the adapter cord, so a script can auto-regulate the charge to keep the battery within the 20-80% range. (Similar questions have been asked for [OpenBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114412/how-do-i-stop-charging-the-battery-way-prior-to-100-in-openbsd) and [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218148/stop-start-battery-charging-through-software), although not answered particularly conclusively).

Note: Taking out the battery would solve this without scripting, which works if I am at my primary workstation. However, at my secondary workstation I need to be able to move around. A scripting solution would be for situations where I'm on the go.

Platforms: HP Pavilion dm4 and Acer Aspire 7741G 5877
OS: `uname -a` on the Pavilion gives `Linux crunchbang 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I could do this by writing to the EC directly. But that was very machine and bios version dependent. I am searching for an acpi method to do the same.